# In function ‘int main(int, char**), ‘MIN’ was not declared

Tags: c++

I am working on Analysis code with ubuntu 18.04, HepMC 2.05.01, root 5.34.38, lhapdf 5.9.1.
When i compile my code i got error;

```
g++ -g -I/home/danisih/compiler/analysis/pythia8153/include -I/home/danisih/compiler/analysis/TAUOLA.1.1.6c-LHC/include Analysistau.cc -o Analysistau.exe -L/home/danisih/compiler/analysis/TAUOLA.1.1.6c-LHC/lib  -L/home/danisih/compiler/analysis/pythia8153/lib/archive -L/home/danisih/compiler/analysis/HepMC-2.05.01/lib -L/home/danisih/compiler/analysis/lhapdf-5.9.1/lib `root-config --cflags --glibs` `fastjet-config --cxxflags --plugins` `fastjet-config --libs --plugins` -lpythia8 -lLHAPDF -lhepmcinterface -lHepMC -lTauolaCxxInterface -lTauolaFortran

Analysistau.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:

Analysistau.cc:221:16: error: ‘MIN’ was not declared in this scope

double max=MIN;
                ^

makefile:24: recipe for target 'Analysistau' failed

make: *** [Analysistau] Error 1
```

How to declare 'MIN' in int main() ???

Comment: Well showing your code would help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: I've just retagged the question to C++. Hopefully that will get it into view of more people who will know what is going on, and get it off the view of Python programmers who will just be confused. If there are more relevant tags, please add them!

Comment: You shouldn't have to declare `MIN`. Clearly that identifier was expected to already be defined. This sounds like a project configuration problem.

Comment: Don't use `MIN` or `MAX`. Use `std::min` and `std::max`.

Comment: What are you expecting `double max=MIN;` to do? We can't tell you the right way to do something if we don't know what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: A useful next step would be to create a [mcve] (and edit that into your question). Then describe what that example is supposed to do (if the compile errors are resolved).

Answer (score -1):

Since the case on MIN is all uppercase and the error looks intelligible I think that macros are giving you trouble.

Just add these lines before main:

```c
double min(double a, double b){ return a<b ? a : b; }
double max(double a, double b){ return a>b ? a : b; }
```

It's best to avoid macros if you can.

Comment: A more generic versions of these functions are already provided in `<algorithm>` as `std::min` and `std::max`.

Comment: Don't add custom (bad) versions of standard functions, please. Just use `std::min` and `std::max`.

Comment: I thought that identifying whether or not their issue was a macro was useful and actionable advice. I wasn't suggestion that they commit to using those two lines of code. Notice the `MIN` and `max` in their error.

Comment: `double max=MIN;` It doesn't look like `MIN` should be a function.

Comment: The compiler error made me think that the compiler was expecting a function named `MIN`. The error message was the only thing to go on. This question had many problem. The file is 200 lines long and the user didn't post any code. I was trying to help them trouble shoot their problem. I didn't expect them to actually use the two lines I posted.

Comment: @shanecandoit When a question has too many problems, it may be better to seek to resolve those problems via comments than to post a wild guess as an answer.